# netbeans find usages does not seem to scan xml files

Tags: java, netbeans

Can anyone confirm this, or do I miss a check in a checkbox somewhere?

Example: When I go to a Java class and do a "Find Usages", it does not find a referance to the class, though it exists in a spring related xml-context file.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this plugin: [JohnBaker FindUsages](http://wiki.netbeans.org/JohnBaker_FindUsages), Spring Support for Find usages. Stock "find usages" from Netbeans doesn't support Spring.

There is also a [generic Netbeans-Spring plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/808/spring-netbeans-module). 
Personally I use [Eclipse with STS](http://www.springsource.org/sts).

Comment: I've used STS but felt more comfortable with Netbeans, I guess they both have their con's and pro's as I sometimes switch to STS in the cases where my frustration with Netbeans gives me a mental breakdown.

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm this for Netbeans 7.2. And that's why some prefer Java spring config.